# What iOS control is correct to use for a custom selectable list?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make a list that will contain an x number of items loaded from a web service. The list would look custom (example below) and selecting a list item would take you to another screen that shows you more details.

I've considered using a table view for this which seems to make the most sense but I'm not sure if that would allow for the level of customization that is needed. Also considering a Collection View which would give more control to how to style it but might bring it's own set of challenges.

Anyone have a recommendation of which one to use or if there's something else that is a better fit that I haven't mentioned?

[image: Mock up of list]

Comment: tableview, collectionview they r same in their way of operation. You might need to look into creating custom cells.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just wanted to see if anyone has a better way to handle it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That would be the `UITableView` and `UITableViewController`. You can easily create custom cell classes, insert and remove cells at runtime, and have a separate datasource or delegate from the `UITableViewController` if you desire.